# How to find the last created/modified method(REST API or salesforce interface or something else) of an Event

Tags: soql, salesforcedx

How to find the last updated method of an event.
My case is, I want to write a SOQL query to get the latest modified Events which are not updated via REST API. So i will get the collection of Events which are updated by users through salesforce interface. Is there any field i can check with this case? I found only *LastModifiedById*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That information is not tracked on sObject records.

You can inspect the user who last modified the record (`LastModifiedById`) to determine if, for example, the record was last modified by an integration user. But you cannot identify the entry point through which the modification took place.